# Asterisk WebSocket ARI events

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari

I can connect to `ws://localhost:8088/ari/events?api_key=user:user&app=hello-world`, but i can't connect to `ws://localhost:8088/ws`. Why?
And how i can to control events through ws?

Answer (score 1):

The ARI websocket connection is read-only. You cannot send messages to Asterisk through it. You must use the rest interface via http to talk to Asterisk, or one of its other interfaces (AMI, AGI).

/ari/events is the correct endpoint to establish a websocket connection. /ws is not.